# str_replace() ignores the count parameter?

Tags: php

As given [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) str_replace() count parameter should stop if certain replacements are done. Right?

Here is my code:

```
define("PLACEHOLDER", "INSERT INTO `listings` VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');".PHP_EOL);
$r = (4 - count($_POST['ad']));
print count($_POST['ad'])."\n";
print $r;
$pf_args = str_replace("'%s', ", "", PLACEHOLDER, $r);
print $pf_args;
```

Now I double-checked everything that `$r = 1` in one my test and to be doubly sure `count($_POST['ad'])` is 3. Still, str_replace completely ignores count parameter and replaces all occurances to give:

```
INSERT INTO `listings` VALUES (NULL, '%s');
```

This is driving me insane. Having seen so much [anti-php](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) talks, such eccentric behaviour(s) mkes me feel that they are bugs or another one of those weird magic it possesses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe $count is used to check how many replacements were performed (for example, if you printed $count after using str_replace(), you would get 10).

You could do what you want to do by using preg_replace() with a little regex. Please see: [How to use str_replace() to remove text a certain number of times only in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703737/how-to-use-str-replace-to-remove-text-a-certain-number-of-times-only-in-php)

Comment: Ok I understand now. May be I should delete this question. Makes me feel really dumb. Can't believe wasted an hour on this.

Comment: understood . interesting

Answer (score 1):

The count parameter does not limit the number of replacements, it simply allows you to see how many replacements were made ...