# PHP why is my fourth parameter in str_replace not working?

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm a beginner in PHP and I can't understand why this does not work.

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$body = 'Biceps, Triceps, Quadriceps, Chest, Calves, Forearms are great to train!';
$body = str_replace('Chest', 'Quadriceps', $body);
$body = str_replace('Calves', 'Triceps', $body);
$body = str_replace('Forearms', 'Biceps', $body);
$body = str_replace('Biceps', 'Forearms', $body, $count);
$body = str_replace('Triceps', 'Calves', $body, $count);
$body = str_replace('Quadriceps', 'Chest', $body, $count);
echo $body;
?>
```

For the latter three replacements, although the fourth parameter, which supposedly defines the number of replacements is set to 1, they still perform the replacement twice and I end up with this output:

> 'Forearms, Calves, Chest, Chest, Calves, Forearms are great to train!'

instead of:

> 'Forearms, Calves, Chest, Quadriceps, Triceps, Biceps are great to train!'

...why?!

Comment: You're interpreting the 4th argument incorrectly.  It is not the number _to be_ performed.  It is the number that _was_ performed.  It is set during execution of the function.

Comment: @PatrickQ set this as an answer

Comment: @Martin Hardly felt like a true answer.  More like a polite RTFM :)  Also, I have a feeling there's dupe for this somewhere, just have to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [str\_replace() ignores the count parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521693/str-replace-ignores-the-count-parameter)

Comment: Good find Nigel, knew there had to be one

Comment: You could always try `strtr()` - example added to answer I've undeleted.

Answer (score 3):

What [the manual](http://php.net/str_replace) say is:

> If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

Additionally, the function signature features the `&` symbol to indicate that the function writes into the variable you pass to it:

> `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

In short, it's a report, not a setting.

Answer (score 2):

Each replace happens before the next is performed.

- In the third replacement, you're changing "Forearms" to "Biceps."
- In the fourth replacement, you're changing it back when you change
  "Biceps" to "Forearms."

Similar problem with 2nd and 4th replacements. The "1" you're passing in to [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) doesn't do anything.

Consider using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) if you only want the first instance to be replaced.

Comment: Sorry this dosen't appear to be talking about the issue actually asked in the post. Maybe best to delete this answer.

Comment: I found this answer most useful though as it not only pointed out the flaw in my approach but also suggests an approach that could work.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter (from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php))...

> **count**
>
> If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

So not the amount to do, but the amount done.

Just as an alternative, try...

```
$body1 = strtr($body, 
    ['Chest'=>'Quadriceps','Calves' => 'Triceps', 
        'Forearms' => 'Biceps', 'Biceps' => 'Forearms',
        'Triceps' => 'Calves', 'Quadriceps' => 'Chest'
    ] );
```

Which outputs

```
Forearms, Calves, Chest, Quadriceps, Triceps, Biceps are great to train!
```